# Square of Binomial Coefficient

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics, it.information-theory

Background

I'm modeling Genetic Algorithm(GA) with Markov chains and deriving the expression for the expectation of the first hittig time in the MC with 1 absorbing state and $l-1$ transient states. This results is an expression for a sum involving square of a binomial coefficient

Problem
I need to find a closed expression for
$$\sum_{k=0}^{l/2} \binom{l/2}{k}^2 p^{2k}$$

where $p$ is a function of $l$ and lies between 0 and 1.

So far I've found a closed expression for 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2 \binom{n}{k}^2$$

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused: why do you think there is hope to find a closed-form formula for your expression without knowing the exact dependence between *p* and *l*?

Comment: @Thierry, if the binomial coefficient weren't squared, there would be the closed-form expression $(1+p^2)^{\ell/2}$, so maybe there's one here, too. 

Comment: OK, let's say $p=\frac{1}{l}$ or $1-\frac{1}{l}$. Does this help. I mean I hope to find such formula as a closed form for arbitrary p. 

Comment: Igor, is there any wat to see how this formula was derived? I have no expreience with Mathematica

Comment: @sigma-z-1980: The general way to evaluate summations like this is "Gosper's algorithm" or its generalization due to Wilf and Zeilberger ("the WZ method"). I think the best place to learn about this is Petkovsek/Zeilberger's book titled "A=B". As you see in my answer, it is easy to wind up with the answer as some sort of a hypergeometric function, which is not always enlightening. You might also look at Kovacic's paper on solving 2nd order ODEs (in the mid-eighties sometime).

Comment: @Igor:

OK thanks. But why is it 'not always enlightning', and what is the $F_{1}$ function in the solution?

thanks

Comment: @sigma, $F_1$ is a hypergeometric function, look it up. 

Comment: Using the notation $n=\ell/2$, your first sum is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the polynomial $(1+x)^n(1+p^2x)^n$. As such, it can be evaluated as the integral of a complex valued rational function on the unit circle of the complex plane. Not that his helps much... As regards the $_2F_1$ expression provided by Mathematica, I believe this function is the exact expansion along increasing powers of $p$ which is written in the original question. :-)

Comment: And (surprise, surprise...) Legendre polynomials may be defined as contour integrals of a given function with respect to $\mathrm{d}z/z^n$ in the complex plane, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html.

Comment: @Didier, I'd be glad if you explained a little bit more how you arrived at this solution. Thanks. What is x btw?

Comment: @sigma, I reckon $x$ is an indeterminate, a placeholder, something to hang a coefficient on. Are you not familiar with the idea of generating functions? 

Comment: @Gerry: I am, I didn't quite get though how Didier arrived at this solution, so it got me confused. 

Comment: @sigma: Sorry I was not more explicit. Here is a way to get at the result. Gerry is right, one works in the space $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of the polynomials wih one indeterminate $x$. Let us forget the coefficient $p$ for a moment and note that ${n \choose k}^2={n \choose k}{n \choose n-k}$, that ${n \choose k}$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $P(x)=(1+x)^n$ and that ${n \choose n-k}$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ in $Q(x)=(1+x)^n$ (yes I know, $P(x)=Q(x)$ but just wait and you will see). (to be cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) The term $x^n$ in the product $P(x)Q(x)$ is obtained by multiplying a term $x^k$ in $P(x)$ by a term $x^{n-k}$ in $Q(x)$ and then by performing the sum over $k$ of these contributions. Hence the sum of ${n \choose k}^2$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $P(x)Q(x)$ (which is simply ${2n\choose n}$, as you know). Now, this was just a warm up because you want these factors $p^{2k}$ in your sum. (to be cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) But this means that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $P(x)$ must be ${n \choose k}p^{2k}$ instead of ${n \choose k}$. You know how to get this modification, do everything as before except that you replace $x$ by $p^2x$ in $P(x)$ and you are done.

Comment: @Didier: thanks this did help a lot. I'm just interested, is this the same as Legendre polynomial in a way as Igor derived in Mathematica? Can you recommend some literature on derivation on closed expressions using binomial coefficients? 

Comment: @sigma Re your first question: this is what I had in mind directing you to the Wolfram page. By the residue theorem, to extract the $x^n$ coefficient of a polynomial $R(x)$ one must integrate $R(z)\mathrm{d}z/(2\pi\mathrm{i}z^{n+1})$ on any positively oriented loop around the origin in the complex plane. If you do that for $R(x)=(1+x)^n(1+p^2x)^n$, an easy change of variable in the integral yields exactly the defining expression of Legendre polynomials. *Et voilà !*

Comment: @sigma Re the derivation of closed expressions for such sums, a "must read" is the book *generatingfunctionology* by Herb Wilf, freely available on his webpage http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf.

Comment: @Didier: yeah it's really helpful. Cheer for this. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Mathematica, your sum equals:

$(1-p^2)^{l/2} \mbox{LegendreP}\left(l/2, \frac{1+p^2}{1-p^2}\right),$

or

$\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{l}{2},-\frac{l}{2};1;p^2\right)$

The second sum is 
$n^2 \binom{2 n-2}{n-1}.$

Ain't technology grand...

**EDIT** The real question is: why do you want to know? The expressions I give above allow you to get asymptotics, get ODE satisfied by the functions, etc, etc. If you want an expression in terms of "elementary functions" (whatever that means in this case), with very high probability there are not any (this is less certain here because these are *definite* summmations). I strongly advise you to read Petkovsek and Zeilberger's "A=B."

Comment: I'd like to get a closed expression because this will provide more understanding of convergence of Evolutionary algorithms, as this probability is important to obtain an exact expression for the expectation of the 1st hitting time.